# Facebook like button links to the FB application - how does this work?

Tags: facebook, wordpress, facebook-like, facebook-opengraph

When I "like" some post within my blog ([www.words4u.cz](http://words4u.cz)) in recent activities on my Facebook account it shows something like "Filip likes post XY in application words4u". How do I remove the part about the application (I want to display just "Filip likes post XY")?

I put this in my header.php file:

```
    <?global $wp_query;
$Magic_no = get_permalink();
$Magic_no_postid = $wp_query->post->ID; 

//echo get_permalink(); 
$data = file_get_contents('http://graph.facebook.com/?id='. $Magic_no);

$json = $data;

$obj = json_decode($json);
$like_no = $obj->{'shares'};
$meta_values = get_post_meta($Magic_no_postid, '_my_key', true);
//$meta_values = 1;
//if ($like_no == '2') {
//   echo "Number of Likes".$meta_values;
if ($like_no == $meta_values) {

} else if (empty($meta_values)) {
add_post_meta($Magic_no_postid , '_my_key', $like_no, true);
update_post_meta($Magic_no_postid , '_my_key', $like_no, false);

} else {
update_post_meta($Magic_no_postid, '_my_key', $like_no, false);

}?>
```

Then when I want to display like button I insert this code directly into the php file (index.php, single.php...):

```
    <div class="fb_like_div">
    <iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/widgets/like.php?href=<?php the_permalink(); ?>&amp;layout=button_count&amp;show_faces=false&amp;width=95&amp;action=like&amp;font&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;height=20&amp;locale=cs_CZ" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" class="fb_like_div_inside" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
    </div>
```

Comment: Could you show me code or plugin name, wht you used for it.

Comment: I edited my thread...hope this is what you've asked for - I originally used the official wordpress FB plugin but it just puzzled me so I chose to insert like button directly.

Comment: i have checked your post like code not working on your site, not showing any kind of msg like that Filip likes post XY in application words4u, do you want to show facebook like button inside every post and after click facebook like button show post title on your facebook a/c

Comment: vikas tyagi: yes thats what I want - I don't want to show any connection with the FB application. Only with the article. But maybe it shows only to me as the facebook app administrator...?

Answer (score 0):

For that use [Sociable](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/sociable/) plugin , and choose facebook like social icon from wp-admin->Select Sociable Plugin->Sociable Options

and put below code end of post code

```
<?php if (function_exists('sociable_html')) { echo sociable_html(); } ?>
```

i hope it will help you, use it tell me if you have any further problem